# How to add main function to pylint missing-function-docstring (C0116) as an exception?

Tags: python, configuration, pylint, linter

How can I avoid pylint to mark missing docstring in the `main` function, without removing any others from the default, like the `__init__` method?

[image]

When I run

```bash
poetry run pylint src/* --no-docstring-rgx "main"
```

it overwrites the default value to avoid private methods that start with `_`. See the docs [here](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/v2.17.0/user_guide/configuration/all-options.html#no-docstring-rgx)

I don't want to override the default configuration, but add more rules to it. Can't figure out a way to achieve that.

Comment: No screenshots of text or code! Copy-paste the text into the question instead. https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557

Comment: What about adding an ignore comment for this line only?

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved with:

```
pylint <module or directory> --no-docstring-rgx "^_|^main$"
```

where,

- `^_` is the [default value](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/v2.17.1/user_guide/configuration/all-options.html#no-docstring-rgx) which matches function and class names beginning with `_`.
- `^main$` matches function and class names with a value of `main`.
- `|` matches either of the previous two regular expressions.

Alternatively, `no-docstring-rgx` can be defined in one of the [configuration files](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/v2.17.0/user_guide/usage/run.html#command-line-options) which Pylint supports. For example a pyproject.toml file in the project root directory can have the following content:

```
[tool.pylint]
no-docstring-rgx="^_|^main$"
```